# Swift - Cannot specialize a non-generic definition

Tags: swift, generics, swift3

I have a function that is responsible for making the HTTP requests in the app. Basically, it sets up all the required headers, timeouts, etc... etc...
Then, when the request is complete, I run 2 functions (provided by the developer): `whenSuccess`/`whenError` (depending on the result of the call) and `whenComplete` (regardless the result of the call). I want the last one to be able to receive the result of the `whenSuccess` function.

I have the `doRequest` function declared as

```
private func doRequest<S>(whenSuccess: (_ json: JSON?)->(S?),
                       whenError: (_ description: String)->(),
                       whenComplete: Optional<(S?)->()>) {
        // yada yada yada
}
```

So, the developer provides a function that gets a `JSON` and returns a generic. If the `whenError` is called, the `whenComplete` is called with `nil` as parameter.

I'm invoking it with

```
doRequest<Int>(whenSuccess: { (json) -> (Int?) in //Cannot specialize a non-generic definition
            return 5
}, whenError: { (error) in

}) { (success) in

}
```

I get the error commented:

> Cannot specialize a non-generic definition

Any idea if this can be done and how?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Swift you must not explicitly specialize generic functions. Instead, generic functions automatically get specialized via type inference from theirs arguments.

The call you you're trying to make should look like this:

```
doRequest(whenSuccess: { json -> Int? in
    //...
}, whenError: { error in
    //...
}, whenComplete: { success in
    //...
})
```

Comment: In other words, drop the "(json) -> (Int?) in" because the compiler is going to figure it out on its own.

Comment: Not at all. Drop `<Int>` after the function name in its call.

Comment: Thanks @werediver , that did the trick! I'm used to verbose languages and coming to swift has its hiccups. I invite you to edit your answer with a piece of code, just for the sake of completeness :)

Comment: But why can't you explicitly specialise generic functions?

Comment: @dented42 It's a language design decision. Explicit specialization of generic functions would be less verbose sometimes, but more cryptic. Explicit specialization of closures in such cases gives more straightforward info for a reader.

Comment: That's a really weird language design decision. Explicit specialization is usually more verbose, but less cryptic.

Comment: With explicit specialization nothing (at the call site) indicates where and how the types are used. With explicitly typed closures (as arguments to generic functions) you immediately see where and how the types are used.